# Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The temperature in $\mathbb R^3$ is given by the function $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R, T(x,y,z) =
3xy + z^3 −3z$. Prove that there are the hottest and coldest points on the
sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 −2z = 0$, and find them.

I found the gradients of T(x,y,z) and the sphere.
$$\nabla T=\pmb{3yi+3xj+(3z^2-3)k}$$  and $$\nabla S=\pmb{2xi+2yj+(2z-2)k}$$
Then we get a system of equations:
3y=$\lambda$2x ; 3x=$\lambda$2y ; 3z^2-3=$\lambda$(2z-2) and the constraint $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 −2z = 0$.

$\lambda$= $\frac{3y}{2x}$ = $\frac{3x}{2y}$ =$\frac{3(z^2-1)}{2(z-1)}$

From the first two I got x=y and $\lambda$ =1, then $\frac{(z^2-1)}{(z-1)}$=1, where z $\neq$1. Solving for z, I got z(z-1)=0, so z=0.

Then I substituted z=0 and x=yto the constraint:

2x^2=0 and got x=y=0.

But I think x and y cannot be 0.

Comment: This is a simple max min problem, you can find examples in the internet easily. At least show what you have tried.

Comment: @JerryCohen , I know it is not a very complicated problem. I keep getting the only answer (0,0,0) which does not seem like the right answer.

Comment: If you show what you did, someone will show where you went wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm okay, I added what I have so far for the solution. Thank you.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are not 0 then $x=y$ or $x=-y$ and $\lambda = \frac{3}{2}$ or $\lambda = -\frac{3}{2}$ respectively.

Comment: $x =\pm y$. $x=-y$ does give some non-trivial values.

Comment: @Paul, thank you!

Comment: @geetha290krm, thank you!

Comment: @geetha290krm with x=-y, I get z=-2 and when I plug it into the constraint equation, I get 2x^2=-8. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=x^2+y^2+z^2-2z=0$

Then $L=f-\lambda g = 3xy+z^3-3z-\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-2z)$

Solve
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=3y-2\lambda x, \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=3x-2\lambda y,\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=3z^2-3-\lambda (2z-2)$$

Which gives us

$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x}{y}=\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}$$

Finally, plug into the constraint:

$$2x^2+1-2=0 \Rightarrow x=\pm 0.707....=-y$$

Now we have 3 candidates for $x$ and $y$ and 1 for $z$. Plug them back into the equation and you will find the max and min.

EDIT: the third candidate is $x=y=0$ in case you missed it, i skiped a few steps, let me know if something's not clear

Comment: first time i answer a question i get dowvoted:) seriously?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I don't get how we get z=-1. In case when x=-y, don't we get z=-2?

Comment: with x=-y, I get z=-2. When I plug it into the constraint equation, I get 2x^2=-8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Amannda So from the $\lambda$ equivalence relation we know $x^2=y^2$, plug back into the constraint you get $2x^2 + z(z-2)=0$. Then we have $x(z-1)=y(z^2-1)$ you get a $z=1$. Now should be clear.

Comment: I think i know where you are confused. Whatever solutions we get, they are a potential candidate for min o max. You have to plug them back into the equation to see the value to know if they are a max or min (or some other points, they have a name for that, i forgot,,,this is quite some time ago)

Comment: @Jerry Cohen on the downvote, it might be that someone considered the answer was substantially given in the comments already (punishment for picking low hanging fruit?). It might be that someone thought a hint for homework was more appropriate than a full solution. I've done both before, but not in this case :)

Comment: @Paul maybe the first version i gave was wrong....Should have written everything o na piece of paper before i type it out. Made a huge mistake during the typing...But i started typing my answer right before these guys gave their hints...well idk...kind demotivating thou....But i remeber your name you helpd me out oncne or twice haha